# To find basis for quotient soace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V=$R^3$ & W be a subspace of V generated by (1,0,0) , (1,1,0). Find basis for quotient space $V/W$.

For finite dimensional vector spaces we have that 
$$
\dim V = \dim Im F + \dim \ker F,
$$

So according to this we must have dimension for $V/W$ as 1.

Now I extend basis for W to basis for V then

Clearly I should have basis for $V/W$ =(0,0,1).

Am I right here?

Comment: $(0,0,1) \not\in V/W$.  I think you mean $\{(0,0,1) + W\}$ which is indeed a basis.

Comment: Yes you are right . Thanks for correction.

Comment: No problem. :-)